# ZF2 optional route constraints in child routes

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-route

I'm having an issue with an optional constraint in a route that is non-optional in it's children. My routing structure is as follows:

```
'profile' => [
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/profile[/:id]',
        'constraints' => ['id' => '[0-9]*'],
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
            'action' => 'profile'
        ]
    ],
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => [
        'sessions' => [
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/sessions',
                'defaults' => ['action' => 'sessions']
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Which to my mind should give me the following routes:

1. `/profile` - works
2. `/profile/123` - works
3. `/profile/sessions` - **doesn't work**
4. `/profile/123/sessions` - works

When I use route 3 in the URL view helper I get the following error:

```
$this->url('profile/sessions');
```

> `Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\InvalidArgumentException`: Missing parameter "id"

I originally had `[0-9]+` as my constraint but making it optional (`*`) doesn't seem to have helped. Has anyone experienced this case before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue once, the only solution I found was to create a separate route (in your case for /profile/sessions) as the optional parameter for the base route, seems to become obligatory when accessing a child route.

Comment: I ended up taking this route as I prefer to clearly define each route (I dislike 'magical' `/:controller[/:action]` style routes).

Answer (score 8):

Add it to your parent route.

```
'profile' => [
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => [                 // ↓ 
        'route' => '/profile[/:id][/:action]',
        'constraints' => [ 'id' => '[0-9]*', 'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*' ],
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
            'action' => 'profile',
        ],
    ],
]
```

This will make it optional to have `id` and/or `action`.
At least in theory it should make all your listed routes possible, there have been [some issues](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-407?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs) with this.